# FreeSync not working for me

Tags: amdgpu

I was wondering if anyone could point out what in doing wrong my specs are

Ubuntu 18.04
5.0.7-050007-generic
mesa 19.0.2 from ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
Im using a RX-580

the file at `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf` is

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "AMD"
Driver "amdgpu"
Option "DRI" "3"
Option "VariableRefresh" "true"
EndSection
```

the output of `xrandr --props` includes `vrr_capable: 1`

the output of `cat ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log | grep amdgpu` is

```
[ 14.653] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[ 14.654] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[ 14.656] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel drive
```

and sadly the output of `cat ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log | grep Variable` is

```
[ 14.794] (WW) AMDGPU(0): Option "VariableRefresh" is not used[ 14.794] (WW) AMDGPU(0): Option "VariableRefresh" is not used
```

Comment: You need to edit your question and ask it in the form of a question. You also need to give more information about your problem, and what you've done to try and fix it.

Comment: I've got the same issue, have you been able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you also update your xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu? You need a a relatively new version like 19.0.0 to be able to use freesync.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will my check my xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu version as soon as possible, probably be 4 days though